# Correct way of using multiprocessing Process() for parallel execution

Tags: python-3.x, parallel-processing, subprocess, multiprocessing

Can I just check with you guys if there is anything fundamentally wrong with my concept in using Python's multiprocessing for parallel execution of an exe file.

So I have a huge bunch of jobs (100000 in the example code) and I want to use all the cores available (16 in my computer) to run them in parallel. The code below doesn't make use of a Queue like many examples that I see around but it seems to work. Just want to avoid the situation where the code "works" but there's a huge mistake lying in wait to blow up when I scale this up to run over several computing nodes. Can anyone help?

```
import subprocess
import multiprocessing

def task_fn(task_dir) :
    cmd_str = ["my_exe","-my_exe_arguments"]
    try :
        msg = subprocess.check_output(cmd_str,cwd=task_dir,stderr=subprocess.STDOUT,universal_newlines=True)
    except subprocess.CalledProcessError as e :
        with open("a_unique_err_log_file.log","w") as f :
            f.write(e.output)
    return;

if __name__ == "__main__":

    n_cpu = multiprocessing.cpu_count()
    num_jobs = 100000
    proc_list = [multiprocessing.Process() for p in range(n_cpu)]

    for i in range(num_jobs):
        task_dir = str(i)
        task_processed = False
        while not(task_processed) :
            # Search through all processes in p_list repeatedly until a 
            # terminated processs is found to take on a new task
            for p in range(len(p_list)) :
                if not(p_list[p].is_alive()) :
                    p_list[p] = multiprocessing.Process(target=task_fn,args=(task_dir,))
                    p_list[p].start()
                    task_processed = True

    # At the end of the outermost for loop 
    # Wait until all the processes have finished
    for p in p_list :
        p.join()

    print("All Done!")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of spawning and managing the processes yourself rather use a [Pool of workers](https://docs.python.org/3/library/concurrent.futures.html#threadpoolexecutor). It is designed to deal with all of that for you.

As your workers are spawning a subprocess, you can use threads rather than processes.

Moreover, it seems that the workers will write on the same file. You will need to protect its access from concurrent instances or the result will be totally out of order.

```
from threading import Lock
from concurrent.futures import ThreadPoolExecutor  


mutex = Lock()
task_dir = "/tmp/tasks"


def task_fn(task_nr):  
    """This function will run in a separate thread."""
    cmd_str = ["my_exe","-my_exe_arguments"]
    try:
        msg = subprocess.check_output(cmd_str, cwd=task_dir, stderr=subprocess.STDOUT, universal_newlines=True)
    except subprocess.CalledProcessError as e:
        with mutex:
            with open("a_unique_PROTECTED_err_log_file.log", "w") as f :
                f.write(e.output)

    return task_nr


with ThreadPoolExecutor() as pool:
    iterator = pool.map(task_fn, range(100000))
    for result in iterator:
        print("Task %d done" % result)
```

Comment: Hey thanks for your reply! Will try it. But so basically there isn't any thing wrong with the way I am coding it?

Comment: Yes there is. As it is, in case of error, your logfile will be all scrambled due to unprotected file access. Moreover, the use of processes there is overkill. Just use threads.

Comment: ok maybe there's a misunderstanding, the "a_unique_err_log_file.log" was my lazy way to say that every log file will be unique. It wasn't meant to be taken literally as in the file name will really be "a_unique_err_log_file.log" so every process will actually be writing to a unique file.

Comment: For the process overkill, what is the impact to the system? more CPU/memory resources needed?

Comment: On Unix, in your specific case, the impact should be negligible. On Windows, each process will have a dedicated memory address space which is quite a lot. Also spawning processes is heavier on Windows. Threads are lightweight in term of memory and creation time on both platforms.

Comment: Ah I see. Thanks for the info!